# perplexing MKMapView issue - need to have addAnnotations in locationManager response

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

This might seem perplexing and ask if more info - I figure I'm just not getting something here.

I have an app that has an MKMapView that is in one VC called VenueViewController. Even though it implements CLLocationManagerDelegate, in this VC, we don't have the map view update in response to the users location.

In the second VC, I extend VenueViewController and we create the MKMapView via a call to [super viewDidLoad]; Annotations are supposed to be added in the super class and we use the locationManager to show the user's current location. The part that is very confusing is that our MKAnnotations which are placed in the super class don't show up in this class. I have to add

```
[self.mapView addAnnotations:self.venues];
```

in the locationManager function. I don't understand why these annotations just won't be added in the parent class which works fine when use by iteslf. Why are these annotations added in the parent class not showing up?

thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Because the parent class doesn't have a mapView.